I would like to compare several rounding rules using both programming simulations and probability theory to find the optimal approach to pay wage
Problem Context:
I came up with this question from a time I worked calculating salaries for interns. I would like to compare several rounding rules using both programming simulations and probability theory to find the optimal approach.

Scenario:

Interns might take additional 'tasks', which are compensated based on the number of hours worked. However, each month, compensation is calculated and paid in full days. The challenge arises when determining how to handle leftover hours that do not make up a full workday.

Goal:

Ideally, the total hours worked in a month are converted into workdays as $\frac{x}{8}$, where $x$ is the total hours worked. However, this division might leave a remainder. Our best scheme should try to minimize the round error.
To be procise, which rounding scheme is closest to the "ideal" compensation, where the interns are paid precisely based on the total hours worked without rounding?

Assuptions

a. The interns are expected to stay for 3 months, or 6 months, or 12 months.
b. The interns' total 'task' per month follows a random distribution. Specifically, the number of tasks per month is uniformly distributed between 0 and 4, and each task takes between 2 and 4 hours (also uniformly distributed).

My schemes

I’ve considered three compensation rounding rules:
(All the 'remaining hours' below mean the totol hours mod 8.)

Plan 1: At the end of each month, any remaining hours greater than or equal to $x_1$ hours are rounded up to a full day, and the remainder is discarded. If the leftover hours are less than $x_1$, they are carried over to the next month. Upon leaving, remaining hours are discarded.

Plan 2: Every month, any remaining hours greater than or equal to $x_{21}$ hours are rounded up to a full day, and the remainder is carried over. Upon leaving, if the remaining hours are greater than or equal to $x_{22}$, they are rounded up to a full day; otherwise, they are discarded.

Plan 3: Each month, any remaining hours greater than or equal to $x_{31}$ are rounded up to a full day, and the remainder is discarded. Upon leaving, any remaining hours are automatically rounded up to $x_{32}$ days, regardless of the amount.



My work and result

Use Python, from scipy.optimize import minimize, use 'Nelder-Mead' method with bounds, after 1000 times simulations, I find the optimized schemes are the second one, with $x_{21}=8, x_{22}=4$ approximately.
The results stay the same even we change the parameters of the distribution in Assumptions b slightly.
Question:
I want to compare the results with a probabilistic approach to see if the findings match.

@YvesDaoust Many thanks to your brilliant intuition. I still want to know for the last month, how to decide the threhold (whether to add one day or to discard).

In floating-point arithmetic the usual rule is “round to nearest, or even”. A non-integer x is rounded to the nearest integer unless it is exactly between two integers. 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 etc. These numbers have one odd and one even integer neighbour and are rounded to the even neighbour: 1.5 to 2 not 1, 2.5 to 2 not 3, 3.5 to 4 not 3 snd so on.
